# Pandas isin on multiply columns

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame

```
    IN_1      IN_2     C_Red   C_Blue  C_Green     
0   Blue     Red        0       0        0          
1   Red      Green      0      Blue      Green      
2   Green    Red        0      Blue       0         
3   Red      Blue      Red      0         0
```

I want to say if any of the values in `C_Red` or `C_Blue` or `C_Green`, appear in either `IN_1` or `IN_2`, then give a 0 to my output column.

```
    IN_1      IN_2     C_Red   C_Blue  C_Green     OUTPUT
0   Blue     Red        0       0        0          1
1   Red      Green      0      Blue      Green      0
2   Green    Red        0      Blue       0         1
3   Red      Blue      Red      0         0         0
```

so far I've done this

```
df.apply(lambda x: [(c in [C_Red,C_Blue,C_Green]) for c in df.loc[x,[IN_1, IN_2]].values] )
```

But can't quite finish it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set`s for check intersection with convert output to bool for `False` if empty set and then pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df.apply(lambda x: bool(set(x[['IN_1','IN_2']]) & 
                            set(x[['C_Red','C_Blue', 'C_Green']])), axis=1)
```

Another solution with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
f = lambda x: x[['IN_1','IN_2']].isin(x[['C_Red','C_Blue', 'C_Green']])
m = df.apply(f, axis=1).any(axis=1)
```

Or solution with list comprehension:

```
zipped = zip(df[['IN_1','IN_2']].values, df[['C_Red','C_Blue', 'C_Green']].values)
m = [bool(set(y) & set(x)) for x, y in zipped]

df['OUTPUT'] = np.where(m, 0, 1)
print (df)
    IN_1   IN_2 C_Red C_Blue C_Green  OUTPUT
0   Blue    Red     0      0       0       1
1    Red  Green     0   Blue   Green       0
2  Green    Red     0   Blue       0       1
3    Red   Blue   Red      0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension fits in here :

```
in_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith("IN")]
c_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith("C")]

df["output"] = [0 if set(val.array).intersection(val1.array) else 1
                for (key, val), (key1, val1)
                in zip(df[in_cols].T.items(), df[c_cols].T.items())
                ]

    IN_1    IN_2    C_Red   C_Blue  C_Green output
0   Blue    Red     0        0         0        1
1   Red     Green   0        Blue      Green    0
2   Green   Red     0        Blue      0        1
3   Red     Blue    Red      0         0        0
```

If your columns are fixed, then you can do the iteration with numpy and hard coded values :

```
df['output'] = [0 
                if set(entry[:2]).intersection(entry[2:]) 
                else 1 
                for entry in df.to_numpy()]
```